# Get sequential number of a row (rank) within a partition without using ROW_NUMBER() OVER function

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I need to rank rows by partition (or group), i.e. if my source table is:

```
NAME PRICE
---- -----
AAA  1.59
AAA  2.00
AAA  0.75
BBB  3.48
BBB  2.19
BBB  0.99
BBB  2.50
```

I would like to get target table:

```
RANK NAME PRICE
---- ---- -----
1    AAA  0.75
2    AAA  1.59
3    AAA  2.00
1    BBB  0.99
2    BBB  2.19
3    BBB  2.50
4    BBB  3.48
```

Normally I would use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` function, so in Apache Hive it would be:

```
select
  row_number() over (partition by NAME order by PRICE) as RANK,
  NAME,
  PRICE
from
  MY_TABLE
;
```

Unfortunately, Cloudera Impala does not support (at the moment) `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` function, so I'm looking for a workaround. Preferably not to use UDAF, as it will be politically difficult to convince to deploy it to the server.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't do it with a correlated subquery, you can still do this with a join:

```
select t1.name, t1.price,
       coalesce(count(t2.name) + 1, 1)
from my_table t1 join
     my_table t2
     on t2.name = t1.name and
        t2.price < t1.price
order by t1.name, t1.price;
```

Note that this doesn't exactly do `row_number()` *unless* all the prices are distinct for a given `name`.  This formulation is actually equivalent to `rank()`.

For `row_number()`, you need a unique row identifier.

By the way, the following is equivalent to `dense_rank()`:

```
select t1.name, t1.price,
       coalesce(count(distinct t2.name) + 1, 1)
from my_table t1 join
     my_table t2
     on t2.name = t1.name and
        t2.price < t1.price
order by t1.name, t1.price;
```

Comment: Instead of using an inner join also a left join is possible, where the "coalesce(..., 1) part may be dropped.

Answer (score 2):

The usual workaround for systems not supporting window functions is something like this:

```
select name, 
       price,
       (select count(*) 
        from my_table t2 
        where t2.name = t1.name  -- this is the "partition by" replacement
        and t2.price < t1.price) as row_number
from my_table t1
order by name, price;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b027/2

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately Impala doesn't support subqueries at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer for how to with Impala, but there are other SQL on Hadoop solutions which do analytical and subquery options already.  Without those capabilities you are probably going to have to rely on multi step process or some UDAF.

I am an architect for InfiniDB
InfiniDB supports analytical functions and subqueries.
http://infinidb.co

Check out Query 8 in the benchmark from Radiant Advisors, it is a similar style query that you are after, utilizing rank analytic function.  Presto is also able to run this style query, just at a slower (80x) pace
http://radiantadvisors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/RadiantAdvisors_Benchmark_SQL-on-Hadoop_2014Q1.pdf

The query from the benchmark (query 8)

```
SELECT
    sub.visit_entry_idaction_url,
    sub.name,
    lv.referer_url,
    sum(visit_ total_time) total_time,
    count(sub.idvisit),
    RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY sub. visit_entry_idaction_url
ORDER BY
    count(sub.idvisit)) rank_by_visits,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sub.visit_entry_idaction_url
ORDER BY
    count(visit_total_time)) rank_by_ time_spent
FROM
    log_visit lv,
    (
SELECT
    visit_entry_idaction_url,
    name,
    idvisit
FROM
    log_visit JOIN log_ action
        ON
        (visit_entry_idaction_url = log_action.idaction)
WHERE
    visit_ entry_idaction_url between 2301400 AND
    2302400) sub
WHERE
    lv.idvisit = sub.idvisit
GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3
ORDER BY
    1, 6, 7;
```

Results

```
Hive 0.12       Not Executable  
Presto 0.57     506.84s  
InfiniDB 4.0    6.37s  
Impala 1.2      Not Executable
```